# Как сохранить последовательные числа из большого диапазона в текстовый файл

Tags: python

Друзья, помогите со скриптом генерации всех чисел в диапазоне (к примеру 1517913125451-2517913125451) и записью в текстовый файл.

```
for i in range(1517913125451, 2517913125451):
    print(i)
```

так получается вывести, но не получается команда сохранения в файл

Comment: обернуть цикл в `with open(file, 'w+') as f:`, а в цикле записывать `f.write(i)`

Comment: Вы же понимаете, что для указанного диапазона получится файл порядка 12 терабайт? У вас есть столько свободного места?

Comment: Спасибо, подскажите как полностью будет скрипт. Про объем знаю

Comment: Покажите свою команду, которая у вас не получается.

Comment: вы можете при запуске перенаправить стандартный вывод в файл: `python3 your-script.py >ouput.txt`

Answer (score 2):

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in range(1517913125451, 2517913125451):
        file.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

Учтите, что последнее число не будет учтено. Поэтому, если этот диапазон Вам нужен включая все числа, следует написать:

```py
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    for i in range(1517913125451, 2517913125451 + 1):
        file.write(str(i) + '\n')
```

Comment: `'w'`, а не `'r'`

Answer (score 2):

Можно так:

```
with open('output.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.writelines("%s\n" % i for i in range(1517913125451, 2517913125451+1))
```

Comment: Настораживает `writelines` и перевод строки внутри - они через строку не получатся?

Comment: Этот код не сработает. `i` - это число, а `%s` позволяет "заместить себя" только строкой

Comment: @MrMorgan, вы уверены? https://ideone.com/QUuPIV

Comment: Значит я ошибся

Comment: @Qwertiy: `writelines()` в Питоне не добавляет новые строки (хотя вы не один так думаете). Этот метод добавили как обратный к `readlines()`, который оставляет новые строки.¶ Я не понимаю, зачем пытаться сутками выводить `10**12` целых чисел в виде ascii, но  `for i in R: print(i, file=file)` вариант медленнее получается чем `file.writelines()`. Чуть быстрее `for i in R: w('%s\n' % i)` работает, где `w=file.write`.

Comment: @jfs, ясно. А последнее предложение предлагаю в ответы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, этот вариант уже есть в ответах.

Comment: @Денис, `print(i, file=file)` - в каком ответе такое есть?

Comment: @Qwertiy, а, я не про то подумал, извиняюсь